# How do I interrupt an SKAction.animate that is repeating forever to run another animation each time the .touchesBegan is called?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, interrupt, repeat

I have a game, in SpriteKit, where the character is using one animation forever to give the illusion he is bouncing along.

```
let frankieTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image1.png")
    let frankieTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image2.png")
    let frankieTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image3.png")

    let frankieBounceAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: [frankieTexture, frankieTexture2, frankieTexture3], timePerFrame: 0.3)
    let makeFrankieBounce = SKAction.repeatForever(frankieBounceAnimation)

    frankie = SKSpriteNode(texture: frankieTexture)

    frankie.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 250, y: self.frame.midY - 450)
    frankie.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width * 0.25, height: frame.size.height * 0.25)

    frankie.run(makeFrankieBounce)
```

Then under the touchesBegan, when the user taps the screen I want to interrupt that animation and replace it for another animation. This one:

```
let frankieOtherAnimationTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "OtherAnimation1.png")
    let frankieOtherAnimationTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "OtherAnimation2.png")
    let frankieOtherAnimationTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "OtherAnimation3.png")
    let frankieOtherAnimationTexture4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "OtherAnimation4.png")

    let frankieOtherAnimationAnimate = SKAction.animate(with: [frankieOtherAnimationTexture1, frankieOtherAnimationTexture2, frankieOtherAnimationTexture3, frankieOtherAnimationTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.2)

    let makeFrankieOtherAnimation = SKAction.repeat(frankieOtherAnimationAnimate, count: 1)
```

How do I get the repeatForever to pause and run the second animation and then restart? I have played with a few if, then statements and can't seem to get it to do it...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Sorry everyone... I realized after fiddling for several hours that I forgot the

```
Frankie.run(SKAction)
```

in my code after my second animation in the .touchesBegan method... It runs fine without having to pause the first animation that is repeating forever.